# Replace object in Array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode6, nsmutablearray

I try to replace a object in a NSMutableArray. To figure out, what the index number is, I use following code:

```
 NSUInteger index = [self.nameArray indexOfObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"James"]];
```

Now I try to replace it:

```
self.nameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:@"Johanna"];
```

But even I want to start the app, I will become an error: Assigning to 'NSMutableArray *' from incompatible type 'void'

Answer (score 2):

Below code is helpful for you.

```
[self.nameArray replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:@"Johanna"];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want to do:

```
[self.nameArray replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:@"Johanna"];
```

Comment: The answer is correct but you don't explain why his approach was wrong. I thing it would be more educational if you explained what he was doing incorrectly.